# innerHTML for div doesn't work if script is seperated

Tags: javascript

I have two files.

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="q2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is q2.js:

```
function go(a) {
  var out = document.getElementById("output");
out.innerHTML = "hdi";
}

window.onload=go()
```

It just doesn't work. it should fill empty div to "hdi", but it doesn't.

However, if i do this in one file wihtout using q2.js, it works, like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
var NUMBERS = 500;
var HEADERS = 20;

function go(a) {
var out = document.getElementById("output");
out.innerHTML = "hdi";
}

window.onload=go()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why this work when using one file but does not work when 2 files are seperated?
Is there a way to do this using 2 files?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be assigning the actual function to `window.onload` but instead you are invoking the function and assigning the return value which is undefined:

Change

```
window.onload=go()
```

To

```
window.onload=go;
```

It only appears to work properly in the second version since the element referenced in the function already exists but it is not actually waiting for the load event to occur.

Comment: Gawd. You answered.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is usually a good practice to put JavaScript code into its own JavaScript file. Better for maintainability and reusability.

Second, it is usually a good practice to put the scripts just before the end of the closing **< /body >** tag, and not in the **< head >**  tag. If your code is in the **head** and references elements further down in the **body**, then it won't be able to see them, because they are not loaded yet.

Your code should work if you move the script just before the closing body

```
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="q2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Not totally accurate. Suppose OP actually wanted images loaded before the function fires...it is not being triggered by load event as it is written

Comment: Yeah, 1) that's why I wrote usually, and not in every case 2) There are no images in the original questions 3) "window.onload" actually becomes redundant if scripts are put at the end of the DOM.